# Open JSON file from PHP to add more data, and save again

Tags: php, json, session

I want to store session specific data in JSON format. I got this part working, but now I want to be able to append data to this file. This is currently a snippit of what I have:

```
$file = 'sessions/' . session_id() . '.json';

$current = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

if (empty($isEnabled)) {   
        $output1 = array($urlStripped => '<img src="images/error.png" height=20 length=20>');
        $output2 = $output1 + $current;
        $contentToFile = json_encode($output2);
}     
else {
        $output3 = array($urlStripped => '<img src="images/vinkje.png" height=20 length=20>');
        $output4 = $output3 + $current;
        $contentToFile = json_encode($output4);
}
file_put_contents($file, $contentToFile);
header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
```

But this is giving me this error: `PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in [..]`. I think that `$current` is a dictonary, and I'm trying to add `$output1` to it which is an array?

Maybe someone could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` decodes into an object, not an array. You can pass `true` as the second argument to use it as an array:

```
$current = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
```

What you currently have tries to merge an array with an object, thus the unsupported operand type.

Comment: Still getting `Unsupported operand types in [..]` for line `$output4 = $output3 + $current;`

Comment: Must be something else in the code than, will try puzzling on my own. thanks for the help.